# Anything wrong with storing user's config data in sessions?

Tags: php, mysql, session

For a website, I want users to choose the way the website looks, so for example if the user chooses the "dark" theme it updates a row in the DB (with either a "config" table or just a column called "theme" in the users table - haven't decided yet)

However, when logging in, is there anything wrong with storing the config options in sessions, or should I just store the ID in a session and query the DB on every page load to get user info?

I'm sure the sessions option would be a lot better for resources, but are there downsides to it (of course when changing the options I would need to make sure the session values are updated too)?

update (with code):

option 1: query DB on each page load -> get value (either "dark" or "light" and use this to display the correct theme)
option 2: users logs in, set "dark" or "light" to a session variable, and use this to display the correct theme

Comment: show the code, it is difficult to help you without seeing the code

Comment: don't really see how code is required for this question? updated anyway

Comment: `is there anything wrong with storing the config options in sessions, or should I just store the ID in a session and query the DB on every page load to get user info?` I think he's just asking about using PHP `$_SESSION` for storing user's website specific config data or not. Not *how* to do it, but _should_ do it or not

Comment: i would go with option 2, and you can also use cookies

Comment: @MarkoD I actually wouldn't use cookies to store too much config data. They could survive a long time with potentially old data.

Comment: if you'd set an option like "remember the theme" then sessions might not be a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it exactly like you said in option 2.

In my opinion it's better to "cache" user related data in the session. This includes anything which may be used frequently in your page.

It's always better to save as many database queries as you can because the database is usually the bottleneck when it comes to the performance of a website. Although there may be situations where it's crucial to always get the newest data.

If there is an additional query with every page request, at some point this may become a significant factor in terms of performance.

As you allready mentioned it's important to update both, the session and the database on a change. For me this is the only downside, at least if we wanna call it that way.